Should we caulk both outside and inside the bottom of shower frame?
I’m a DIY novice — so please forgive any informal speak here:
Just moved into a house and the shower frame was previously caulked at the bottom on the inside AND outside.
The caulk was clearly deteriorated and mold was growing, particularly at the areas where caulk contacted the grout.
We stripped the caulk, but now we’re questioning if we need or should caulk both inside and outside since everyone says that’s a big culprit for mold growth.
Most we’ve read on here says to only do one or the other, unless the manufacturer says to do both. The etching is unreadable so we can only see Trulite, but can’t tell what model the frame is to look up further (or maybe we’re not looking in the right place).
So far we’ve caulked the outside since that seems to be the most recommended option. It was the first time we’ve ever caulked, so feedback is welcome too! 
Here’s pictures of the inside (started some prep work but didn’t start caulking yet):



We don’t see any weep holes, but also not sure if that’s just cause we don’t know where to look for them or if they truly don’t exist :’)
Should we caulk both inside and outside? Please help!

When I installed my shower-screen, the instructions that came with it, said to only caulk outside on the horizontal channel section against the tray, with caulk also on the inside on the verticals, and 2/3 of the way up outside
I believe the un-caulked horizontal inner edge allows for any water that does get in there, to drain.

This may be a regional thing, but when I had any shower glass installed in my rental properties or my own home the installers caulked the inside and the outside.
I believe the idea is to caulk to prevent water from getting under the frame. This cannot be achieved without caulking the inside.
I had a frameless glass panel installed in a shower and the installers, ( From a very reputable local company) Installed the glass in a bed of caulk and cleaned off the excess.
Of course manufacturers may have their prefered methods which state caulking only the outside. This usually is because they have a seal or gasket that keep water from infiltrating.  However the seal/gasket may have deteriorated, and this method is no longer viable.

Theoretically, caulking only the inside will be enough of a water seal, but you will get water coming under from outside (splash/drip), so it's better to keep water from getting under the frame and forming mold.  So better to just double up.
